# Convert formatted time to UTC milliseconds

Tags: datetime, go, unix-timestamp

How to convert time in format

```
2009-01-01T01:02:01.111+02:00
```

to UTC in milliseconds?

Is there already package for this conversion? I looked at the https://golang.org/src/time/format.go but couldn't find same format to convert.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`time.Parse`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Parse).

Demo: http://play.golang.org/p/ouiDtIVjQI

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    t, e := time.Parse(`2006-01-02T15:04:05.000-07:00`, `2009-01-01T01:02:01.111+02:00`)

    if e != nil {
        panic(e)
    }

    fmt.Println(t.UTC().UnixNano() / 1000000)
}
```

Use the format string `2006-01-02T15:04:05.000-07:00` for the reference date.

Comment: Thanks for response, but what is reference string for ? I should get milliseconds in UTC ( from 1970. I think )

Comment: @PaolaJ. When parsing a time specified as a `string`, you have to specify the layout, the format of the input string. This basically tells what part of the input is the year, month, day, hour, min etc. The solution in this answer does print the milliseconds since the [epoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time). Please click on the link and run the code.

Comment: Btw `UTC()` in `t.UTC().UnixNano()` is not necessary. Number of milliseconds since the epoch doesn't depend on time zone.

Comment: @kostya that's what I thought but still put it in there for good measure :P

Answer (score 1):

the format is pretty standard ISO8601, so you can use the `time.RFC3339` layout, e.g.

```golang
t, e := time.Parse(time.RFC3339, "2009-01-01T01:02:01.111+02:00")
```

- [playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/M7bukF-4Pk6)

...and proceed with `.UnixNano()` as in [thwd](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30372823/10197418)'s answer. More predefined layouts can be found in [src/time/format.go](https://golang.org/src/time/format.go).